# Cannot record touch move without a touch start

Tags: react-native, console.log

When i run my react native code it gives error and says **console.error: 'cannot record touch move without a touch start. '**

but in case when I run my code the second time it does not show this type of error and code runs successfully. What is the reason behind this error ?  Please suggest me any answer.

Comment: Put this in app.js or root file of your app.
`console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;`

Comment: Please share your test code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './src/controller/MYclass';
console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false; // copy paste this line in your App.js 
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MYclass/>
    );
  }
}
```

> console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;

paste the above code in your App.js

Comment: and it is enough to hide the warning or you should solve it ! ^_*

Comment: I almost killed my tomato plants with this answer.